# AngularUI ng-grid useExternalFilter partially

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I want to provide external filtering logic (to enable server side call each time, users enters new filter text) to my ng-grid, but still want to use input box which comes with grid as input-text. 
My Settings are :-

```
  $scope.filterOptions = {
              filterText: "",
              **useExternalFilter: true**
          };
  $scope.$watch('filterOptions.filterText', function (newVal, oldVal) {
              if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                  $scope.getPagedDataAsync();
                  $scope.totalVehicles = 0; //reset totalVehciles, so that new count as per filter text retrieved
              }
          }, true);
```

I was assuming that built-in filter input box has set ng-Model to  $scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText property. But watch is not firing on change of text to that text box.
[image]